# Assign custom emergency calling policy sometimes works and most of the time get cant be assign to individuals

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business

> Did anyone experience this issue before? I did follow MS article on how to create Emerg calling policy and Emerg call routing policy and use the PS commands they provided to assign these policies to individual users but I keep getting cant assign this policy for individual and when I try Admin portal I get this error:

We were able to assign some users to the policies. However, there are other users that can't be assigned to these policies: Emergency call routing policy. If you continue to have problems, contact Microsoft customer support.

When I use Powershell:

Grant-CsTeamsEmergencyCallingPolicy -Identity user1 -PolicyName SecurityDeskNotification
Policy "Policy Name"

> is not a user policy. You can assign only a user policy to a specific user.

- CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Grant-CsTeamsEmergencyCallRoutingPolicy], ManagementException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Rtc.Management.AD.ManagementException,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.AD.Cmdlets.AssignTeamsEmergencyCallRoutingPolicyUsingLros
- PSComputerName : admin1a.online.lync.com

Strangely sometimes it does work and other times it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Please share both user proprieties for whom policy was assigned successfully and other user who received the error, also please provide more context how your applying policy to bulk users, is it importing users or through security group , no. of users ,attach the screenshot of custom policy as well

Comment: **Part 1 - Please see the code below I use to assign the polices to the bulk of users from CSV file**   '$SAVE = Import-Csv  -path yarab1.csv -Header Identity'  'now I assign the value for Emg Calling and Routing P'$CsTeamsEmergencyCallingPolicy = "Global","Emg BOT ", "US and CA Emg CP" | Out-GridView  -PassThru -Title "Please Choose the T EMG R&C   Policy" $TeamsEmergencyCallRoutingPolicy = "Global", "SCEMRN", "US Emergency Calling routing" | Out-GridView  -PassThru -Title "Choose Voice Calling Routing P'**Now get the user list and assign the Emg Policy**

Comment: **Part 2 - now assigning the store values to the users using the code below** ' try { $SAVE |  Foreach-Object {Grant-CsTeamsEmergencyCallRoutingPolicy  -Identity $_.identity -PolicyName   $TeamsEmergencyCallRoutingPolicy -ErrorAction }
    $SAVE   | Foreach-Object {Grant-CsTeamsEmergencyCallingPolicy  -Identity $_.identity -PolicyName $CsTeamsEmergencyCallingPolicy}
     
            }
    catch {
     
      Write-Host "An error occurred: !" -ForegroundColor Yellow -BackgroundColor  Red 
    }'

Comment: Hi Yallabina, Policy is dependent on below attribute. Microsoft.Rtc.Management.AD.UserIdParameter . Kindly check user having proper license also before executing the command.

Comment: Hi Kartheek, thank you for your reply, but if its permission issue. I have a script that uses foreach-object and assigns the policy to 90 users using same username and password, but the script keeps prompting for the password after max ten users, and the only way it accepts the same username and password is by waiting for 5 to 8 minutes before adding my username and password again, and the script will run for ten more users, and then it happens again all over.

Comment: Hi Yallabina, i copied your script and executed. haven't received error for 25 users. from script side there are no issues.  if you are still facing the issue. use batch or group operation to assign policy to bulk users. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/assign-policies